# Overwrite fields in Django Serializer

Tags: django, django-serializer

I am new in Django and I would like to overwrite the field value in `create` and `update` method of serializer. Here is my model=>

```
class Holiday(models.Model):   
    HolidayDay = models.DateField()   
    Created_DT = models.DateTimeField()
    Created_Usr = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    LastModified_Usr = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    LastModified_DT = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.HolidayDay)
```

Here is my serializer=>

```
class HolidaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:        
        model=Holiday
        fields = [
            'id',
            'HolidayDay',           
            'Created_DT',
            'Created_Usr',
            'LastModified_Usr',
            'LastModified_DT'
        ]

        def create(self,validated_data):  
            validated_data['Created_Usr']  ="Testing"       
            return Holiday.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I would like to update `Create_usr` field value in `create` method and `LastModified_usr` field in `update` method. But why I can't overwrite the create_usr field as "Testing"?

Here is my views=>

```
def post(self,request):
        holiday = request.data.get('holiday')      

        serializer = HolidaySerializer(data=holiday)

        serializer.is_valid()      
        print(serializer.errors)

        if serializer.is_valid():           
            holiday_saved=serializer.save()

        return Response({"success":"Holiday '{}' created successfully".format(holiday_saved.HolidayDay)})

    def put(self,request,pk):
        save_holiday = get_object_or_404(Holiday.objects.all(),pk=pk)
        data = request.data.get('holiday')
        serializer = HolidaySerializer(instance=save_holiday,data=data,partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True):
            holiday_saved=serializer.save()

        return Response({"sucess": "Holiday '{}' updated successfully".format(holiday_saved.HolidayDay)})
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message (either in Python or over HTTP from the API)? Or is the `Holiday` object being created but with the wrong `Created_Usr` value?

Comment: @HenryWoody,I don't get any error message and created_usr value is created with other value.

Comment: In your code the create function is under class Meta and not the HolidaySerializer class. Is that a "typo" due to posting here or is it like this in your code?

Comment: @hendrikschneider, If u answer this cmd, I will do accept this one. yes, I am the wrongly write inside the metaclass. Sry I come from .net development so this writing style is quite different for me. Thank for your cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create method is not defined in your Serializer class, instead it is part of your Meta class. You should be able to solve it by moving your create method to your HolidaySerializer:

```
class HolidaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self,validated_data):  
        validated_data['Created_Usr']  = "Testing"       
        return Holiday.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:        
        model=Holiday
        fields = [
            'id',
            'HolidayDay',           
            'Created_DT',
            'Created_Usr',
            'LastModified_Usr',
            'LastModified_DT'
        ]
```